# C++ Vulgar fraction

Tags: c++, variables

Is there a vulgar fraction that can be used as a variable?

For example: I want to divide the integers 1 and 3. The result as `int` is 0, as `double` result is `0,333333333`. However, I want the result to be exactly `1/3`, and later to use it in other equations in the program.

Is there a variable similar to the integer (`int`), decimal (`double`), e.t.c. (that is being declared and used in a similar way)? Or do I have to make one myself?

At first I was thinking how to make it myself, but I failed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in the core language, but there are libraries, such as [boost::Rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/rational/index.html).

Comment: If you replace the version number in a link to a boost library by `release`, the link will always be resolved to the most recent version of Boost (so your answer will never be out-of-date).

Comment: I have a feeling that learning how to use the library will take me some time. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure what it is that you are asking, but have a look at [Boost.Rational](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/rational/index.html).

With it you can write code such as:

```
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
boost::rational<int> one(1);
boost::rational<int> three(3);
boost::rational<int> one_third(one / three);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no rational numbers in stl now, it will be part of stl in c0x - upcomming c++ standart. You can try [boost](http://www.boost.org/), or write by yourself.

Comment: c++11 is reality. It was passed back in August. However, until compiler support all the features etc, it will take some tim.